# ReportViewer in Azure Functions: mscorlib: The path is not of a legal form

Tags: c#, function, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-functions

I'm migrating simple ASP Web API to Azure Functions, for the first time. The function will take some JSON input, and creates a PDF report with Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.

Unfortunatly, I get the following error:

> Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerCSharp1. Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms: An error occurred during local report processing. Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common: The definition of the report 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTriggerCSharp1\bin\Test.rdlc' is invalid. Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common: An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing. Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.IntermediateFormatVersion' threw an exception. mscorlib: The path is not of a legal form.

First I thought that the .rdlc file was not found, but that doens't seems to be the case. It finds the file, but can't handle it, so it seems.

I'm calling the file via:

```
ReportViewer rv = new ReportViewer();
rv.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
rv.LocalReport.ReportPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME"), @"site\wwwroot\HttpTriggerCSharp1\bin\Test.rdlc");
```

I've searched a lot, but can't find specifics on Azure Functions and ReportViewer. Maybe I'm missing something, or I'm trying something that's not possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note familiar with ReportViewer but it is possible that you are hitting a Sandbox issue. See: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#microsoft-sql-reporting-framework-manually-generating-pdfs

Comment: Quote from the site mentioned: 
The following PDF generators are supported:
SQL Reporting framework: requires the site to run in Basic or higher.

Comment: @LingToh Is there maybe someone in the Azure-Functions teams, who could help me?

Comment: Is your Function running on an App Service or Consumption Plan?

Comment: It's running on an App Service, Basic Plan.

Comment: FYI -- looking into this here as well: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0b4fd367-200a-4f5b-938b-286e0a8c78cc/reportviewer-in-azure-functions-mscorlib-the-path-is-not-of-a-legal-form?forum=AzureFunctions&prof=required

Answer (score 1):

From the [Azure official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sqlclassic/virtual-machines-windows-classic-sql-server-reportviewer), we could know that **ProcessingMode.Local** is not supported in the Microsoft Azure.

> ReportViewer configured in local processing mode is not supported in Microsoft Azure

The following is the snippet of document, more details please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sqlclassic/virtual-machines-windows-classic-sql-server-reportviewer).

> To incorporate ReportViewer into your Microsoft Azure Web site, you need to complete the following tasks.
>
> - Add Assemblies to the Deployment Package
> - Configure Authentication and Authorization
> - Publish the ASP.NET Web application to Azure

**Update:**

According to the [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0b4fd367-200a-4f5b-938b-286e0a8c78cc/reportviewer-in-azure-functions-mscorlib-the-path-is-not-of-a-legal-form?forum=AzureFunctions&prof=required), currently, this library *does* work with Web Sites and WebJobs, but not with Functions due to the nature of how we load assemblies.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. However, I'm not sure if the statement about the Local Processing mode is up to date. That's because I already have my Web API up and running in Azure which is using the local processing mode. Now i want to port it to an Azure Function.

Comment: According to the [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0b4fd367-200a-4f5b-938b-286e0a8c78cc/reportviewer-in-azure-functions-mscorlib-the-path-is-not-of-a-legal-form?forum=AzureFunctions&prof=required), `this library *does* work with Web Sites and WebJobs, but not with Functions due to the nature of how we load assemblies.`

Comment: Hi Tom, I know, that post was also created by me :) Thanks!

Comment: Please closed it if it is resovled that will make other communities easily to search.

Comment: Please vote for this to be supported within Azure Functions: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/17336995-need-to-allow-gdi-access-for-running-reportviewer